# Search on Title which contains dots only work for complete string

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

I'm having a strange issue when searching on the default Title column in a SP list.

My content in the Title column is like this:
"Warehouse.Location.Paris.France"

If I search for a complete word between the '.' I get the result. But if I search for only a part of the word I don't get the result. Which doesn't make sense to me.

So searching on "Warehouse" will get me result. But searching on "Ware" will get me nothing.

Is the dot a special character in the search? How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the search in SharePoint works, when you use words in a free-text KQL query, Search in SharePoint returns results based on exact matches of your words with the terms stored in the full-text index. You can use just a part of a word, from the beginning of the word, by using the wildcard operator (*) to enable prefix matching.

You can search like: Ware*
[image]

Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Hi Lisa, OK thanks for your answer! I didn't realise that!